# I am having problem in redirecting through header tag

Tags: php

I am trying to redirect in a different page in successfull insertion of data. But having problem in this. When I am submitting the data, it is being saved in the database but not redirecting in the page I want. I think something is wrong in the 'header' function.

Here is the full php code

```
<?php
session_start();
include('includes/header.php'); 
include('includes/connection.inc.php');
include('includes/preloader.php');
include('includes/function.inc.php');
$msg="";
$error="";
$status_x=0; 
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$admin=get_safe_value($con,$_SESSION['username']);
if(isset($_GET['idtoassign'])){
$id=get_safe_value($con,$_GET['idtoassign']);
$_SESSION['id']=$id;
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(isset($_GET['idtoassign']) &&isset($_GET['title']) &&isset($_GET['imdbId'])){
 $title=get_safe_value($con,$_GET['title']);
 $id=get_safe_value($con,$_GET['idtoassign']);
$imdbId=get_safe_value($con,$_GET['imdbId']);

}

if(empty($id)){
//Creating an unique id for the entity
$rand=rand();
while(1){
$sql="select * from moviecatalog where id=".$rand;
$exc=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if($exc){
  $num=mysqli_num_rows($exc);
  if($num!=0){
    $rand=rand();
  }else{
    $idtoassign=$rand;
    break;
  }
}
}   
}
else{
$idtoassign=$id;
}




$trailler=get_safe_value($con,$_POST['youtubetrailer']);
$date=date("d/m/Y");
$time=date("h:i:s");
$sql="select * from moviecatalog where title='$title'";
$exc=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$movieexist=mysqli_num_rows($exc);
if($movieexist>0){
$msg.="Title is allready exist!";
}else{

if(!empty($_POST['genre'])){
foreach ($_POST['genre'] as $key => $value){
$genreF= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$value);
$ins1="insert into moviecatalog (title,genre,id, imdbId,trailler, date, time, admin, status) 
values('$title','$genreF','$idtoassign','$imdbId','$trailler','$date',
'$time','$admin','1')";
$execute=mysqli_query($con,$ins1);
if($execute){
$status_x=1;
}else{
$status_x=0;
}
   }
}else{
  $msg="Please Select Atleast One Genre!";
}

}


}

     if($status_x==1){
         //echo "hiiii";
         header("Location: https://cinelove.online/adminpanel/moviemaster.php");
         //die();
     }else{
         $msg.="Data could not insert";
     }

}else{
header('location:https://cinelove.online/adminpanel/login2.php');
}

?>
```

Please someone help me

Comment: The echo statement before the header  was working fine,which I commented down later.

Comment: Is there any output send before the header("location"), maybe in your "header.php" ? Headers *must* be send before any output!

Comment: call `exit()` immediately after `header()` function and try again

Comment: and one important instruction, if you use plain PHP with no raw html, never end script with `?>`. It will not create any error. but if you left any extra space after `?>` that will be output a white space in output stream.

Comment: No output send before the header("location"). I checked it once more but it is okay.
** Is it beacuse of the preloader I used in the top? I removed the preloader file now ,and it is working. What is the issue with the preloader? Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your responses and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in there was a complete html file inside the preloader file which is included in the 3rd line. Thats why it was not being able to redirect properly. Thanks everyone for your support.